# Error in uploading video from java to php server

Tags: java, http

I am developing a java application which can send video to a php server.
I had done it on android and the code below is working perfect on android but now when I tried this code in pure java(not android) I got exception.
This is my java desktop code that uploads a video to php

```
try {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                "http://b....vedioup.php");

        FileBody filebodyVideo = new FileBody(new File(Path));
        StringBody title = new StringBody("Filename: " + Path);
        StringBody description = new StringBody(
                "This is a description of the video");

        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        reqEntity.addPart("videoFile", filebodyVideo);
        reqEntity.addPart("title", title);
        reqEntity.addPart("description", description);
        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

        // DEBUG
        System.out
                .println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

        // DEBUG
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
        if (resEntity != null) {
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
        } // end if

        if (resEntity != null) {
            resEntity.consumeContent();
        } // end if

        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

    }
```

and this is the output in console.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.<init>(AbstractHttpClient.java:187)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.<init>(DefaultHttpClient.java:146)
at BlankFoem.uploadFile(BlankFoem.java:351)
```

It is clear that its an exception of class not found but how can I fix it.

Thanks

Comment: the error mainly talks about a missing class, this class is in a lib jar i think you need to include `apache commons: logging` jar in your class path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a deprecated class, `DefaultHttpClient`. Here is its [API Documentation](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html). As you can see, it is marked as deprecated, and they recommend using `HttpClientBuilder` instead.

Using the deprecated class calls a parent class (also deprecated) which requires a logging factory. I assume the `apache.commons.logging` jar is not installed in your classpath, and therefore you get this particular exception.

It would be better to use `HttpClientBuilder` as they recommend rather than installing the logging jar.

And the reason that it worked on android was because you probably had an older version of the apache HttpClient library there.

Here is a link to the new [Apache HTTP Components library](http://hc.apache.org/), including all the documentation and downloads.

Answer (score 1):

just add this jar file `apache.commons.logging` to your project and you are done

Answer (score 0):

Oh man you just have to add

```
apache.commons.logging jar
```

in to your project.
Silly